# C# Watin - Skipping the iteration whenever browser throws a popup (message from webpage)

Tags: c#, watin

Watin is unable to catch the browser popups with IE 9. Instead I would like to skip it and continue with rest of the program if such popup is thrown. Is it possible to skip in such a fashion?

Popups are JavaScript popups.

Comment: Although it does look like your question may have enough information in it for someone to perhaps help you. You should include any research effort you have made

Comment: What popups? How are they created? Are they JS popups? What do the popups actually mean? As in, why are you ignoring them?

Comment: Arran -- sorry i missed to mention earlier. Yes they are JS popups

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the Popup's are JS popups, You can not ignore them and continue as the browser main window goes light and the control gets on the popup message.

you can try like

```
var browser = new IE();
var url = "someurl";
browser.GoTo(url);
```

//After some navigation a popup aapers

//when popupappears control does not automatically returns to code and gives a timeout while IE was busy exception.

So we need to use here

```
somebtton.ClickNoWait() //In case of Button Click

browser.GoToNoWait()   // In case of pop up appearing just after navigation.


            //Finds the alert dialog if it appears
        AlertDialogHandler AlertDialog = new AlertDialogHandler();
        try
        {
            //Code for checking if the case number is invalid and a dialog box appears.
            Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = true;
            Settings.AutoCloseDialogs = true;

            browser.AddDialogHandler(AlertDialog);

            AlertDialog.WaitUntilExists();

            //If alert dialog is found then close the dialog and log error
            if (AlertDialog.Exists())
            {

                //Click OK button of the dialog so that dialog gets closed
                AlertDialog.OKButton.Click();
                browser.WaitForComplete();
                browser.RemoveDialogHandler(AlertDialog);                    

            }
        }
        catch
        {
                //Removes the dialog handler if the Dialog dosen't appear within 30 secs.
                browser.RemoveDialogHandler(AlertDialog);               
        }
```

Try it and if you still face the problem, show some code like what you are doing.